# WebStorm Run Configuration Error `sh: 1: npm: not found` after updating node version

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, nvm

In WebStorm, while using nvm, after updating from node 14 to 16, I updated an existing run configuration from 14 to 16, then I got this error:

```sh
/path/to/node /path/to/npm-cli.js run build --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
npm run build
sh: 1: npm: not found
```

All of the paths to node and the cli were correct. Copy-pasting the command from the output into a terminal launched the npm script correctly.

Comment: error shows that `npm` is not in your `$PATH`; what OS is it? Try starting the IDE from terminal - does the issue persist?

Comment: @lena I posted the answer when I asked the question. I simply deleted the run config and recreated it. npm functioned correctly in a terminal when copying & pasting the same command from the output in the Run tab/window. Something was screwed up inside WebStorm. I posted this so anyone else encountering this problem could avoid wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the run configuration, and recreate it (e.g. click the play (green triangle) icon in the `package.json` gutter next to the script to run)